# How do I get user input when in R console

Tags: user-input

How do I get user input from the terminal?
I write my R program in Notepad then copy it into R Console to run.  My program needs user input.
If I use readline it does not pause for user input but picks up the following line of 'code' as its response.
Similarly with cat or cat & scan whether they are used within functions or in-line.
Example:    (the xxread1:4 are there to stop the program producing errors)

```
read_message=function()
   {xx<-readline('does it appear? ')}
readkey <- function()
   {cat("[press [enter] to continue]")
     number <- scan(n=1,what='character')}
x=read_message()
xrread1='1'
x=readline(prompt='Is it real? ')
xrread2='2'
gh=readkey()
xrread3='3'             
cat("[enter field]")
number <- scan(n=1,what='character')
xrread4='4'
number
```

I know this does not look like valid code, but run it -- it works but
does not pause for user input, the results of the reads,etc are the following numbers.
So how do I get user input?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
You have to source the whole program -- save it to a filename, then in R console

```
source(filename)
```

I had tried just sourcing the functions then copy/pasting the rest into R console -- that did not work, it has to be the whole program (as far as I've discovered).